# Spring Jpa data Generic query

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

ı have such a generic repoistoryy

```
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T , Long> {}
}
```

my question: I want filter this results. Example

I have A User Entity

```
@Column
Private boolean isActive;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private SystemManagerEntity systemManagerEntity;
```

and SystemManager Entity

```
    @NotNull(message = nameNull)
    @NotBlank(message = nameBlank)
    @Size(min = 3 , message = nameLenght)
    @Column(name = "system_manager_name",nullable = false)
    private String SystemManagerName;
```

I want to filter these two entities by their id and name.I tried to write a Criteria api and a custom query, but I couldn't get it to work. How should I go about it? Note: ı use Spring data

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Do your `User` and `SystemManager` entities extend `BaseEntity`?  And how? Is `BaseEntity` annotated as `@MappedSuperclass`? If so why you have defined id properties in the entities? And a major inconsistency, you have declared that your `BaseRepository` assumes `String` as primary key  `...extends JpaRepository<T , String>` however in your entities you have defined `long` id. Please share more of your code, there are many inconsistencies.

Comment: hi you can use JPA Buddy plugin for your ide to help you make better query or repository managements

Comment: Yes ı Extend. and Annotated @MappedSuperClass. this example is boilerplate code. I ask just, how write a query or criteria api.

Comment: Please don't post code that does not match with the one that you have problems with. You see I tried to read your code and pinpoint you some inconsistencies but if that's not the real case, its misleading and I just lost my time. Moreover how we can suggest you a query or criteria api code without having the correct Entities or classes?  *.I tried to write a Criteria api and a custom query, but I couldn't get it to work.* Can you share the code you wrote for this?